# Creating a DataFrame in PySpark gives pyj4 error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am working in a windows 7 environment, running my code on the windows command prompt. I am running a very simple set of code of right now.

```
data = [('Alice', 1), ('Bob', 2)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)
```

Which gives me the errors

```
 py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.applySchemaToPythonRDD.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.
```

There is much more error output following but the actual error is the first line. I've looked up this error on other post but they don't concern actually creating a dataframe.

I looked at the runtime exception as well and saw there was an error trying to get file permissions. I tried running my command prompt in administrator mode instead but it didn't help.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: 2.0.2, the most recent version

Comment: I'm also running python 3.5. It wasn't specified I needed to run python 2.7